# Why is everyone dead?

Tags: cities-skylines

I have been playing cities skylines for a while now and every now and again my city goes through the 'plague', where pretty much the entire city falls sick (see image below).

My water pollution is 0% and have more than sufficient crematoriums to accommodate the dead.

A few google searches point to water pollution but that is not the issue here... Any ideas what could be going on?

[image]

Comment: This might seem dumb, but you do have ample hospital coverage? Also your screenshot shows quite a few dead, maybe your crematoriums' hearses are having problems getting to your dead. Doesn't matter how much space you have if it takes a long time for pickup.

Comment: Yup, ample hospital coverage. This 'event' only happens intermittently though, its not constant.

Comment: I would look into crematoria as well. Sick people that die and don't get picked up cause the surrounding area to lose value, which causes people to move out and explains all your abandoned houses. Eventually the dead people get replaced by new ones that die when they're older which explains the intermittent nature of the problem. Maybe crematoriums are emptying, causing the hearses to be entirely busy at that time?

Comment: Its most defiantly not a crematoria issue, no matter how many I place I still get the issue.

Comment: Those people aren't sick, they're dead.

Comment: Did you have (several) population booms? As in, did you build nearly an entire section or residential while paused and then let them populate? This could be a symptom of that, nearly everyone who moved in dying of old age at the same time.

Comment: no population booms, steady growth.

Comment: Just found this reddit post, its supposedly a bug: https://www.reddit.com/r/CitiesSkylines/comments/2z7pia/im_seeing_a_major_bug_that_also_plagued_banished/

Comment: Well, that escalated quickly.

Comment: The major problem you might have in your city is traffic. There might be plenty of deathcare coverage but if the traffic is heavy, they won't be able to pick up the deaths in a timely manner.

Comment: Could also be ground pollution (hard to see in the picture) from garbage piling up recently.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based upon information from online threads and in-game experience it appears that citizens will die at specified intervals based upon when the residential zone was created.  There appears to be a few ways to combat this:

- Make sure not to zone in large bursts.  Meaning that you should zone a few sections of residential as time goes on and not in one large block while paused.
- Ensure that you have plenty of Crematoriums and Graveyards that can easily access all areas of your residential zones.

Sources:
[first](https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/index.php?threads/death-waves.843503/), [second](http://www.reddit.com/r/CitiesSkylines/comments/2znvat/next_patch_needs_to_deal_with_the_waves_of_death/), [third](http://steamcommunity.com/app/255710/discussions/0/610575007206783158/?insideModal=1), [fourth](http://steamcommunity.com/app/255710/discussions/0/610575007218828809/?insideModal=1)

Comment: Since I could only post 2 sources in my OP here are a few more with similar information: [1](http://steamcommunity.com/app/255710/discussions/0/610575007206783158/?insideModal=1), [2](http://steamcommunity.com/app/255710/discussions/0/610575007218828809/?insideModal=1)

Comment: To add to this answer, check your city's Death and Population statistics. If the answer applies to your situation, you will see the line fluctuating wildly.

Comment: This seems like the answer.  It does kind of stink that I need to have 30 crematoriums in my city of 80,000 to handle these spikes.  The game is off a bit in this respect.

Comment: @Bob you don't need 30. But if 80% of those 80k die at the same time because you invited them to your city at the same time, then you have to handle that. As already said above, increase your pupulation in intervals, then you may need maybe a max of 10 crematoriums for 80k.